# How can we do partial page updates in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, partial

We want to show Some fields of table in Detail view layout and want to update every fields individually. can we do this in `asp.net`

Comment: As new user just suggestion, dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want....

Answer (score 2):

Use `UpdatePanel` and `ScriptManager`.

See here for details:[Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of AJAX that will do the task for you ...

You can make use of AJAX-Toolkit control [**UpdatePanel**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) to do the partial update of your page. Also check : [Implement ASP.NET AJAX with the UpdatePanel control](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314488/pranay-rana)